# Regex pattern to skip a pattern and match another pattern

Tags: regex

I have the following string value:

```
https://<host_name>/path/object.svc/path1/path2|https://<host_name>/path/xyz.svc/path3/path4.
```

The `object.svc` is always fixed in the string, but the part `xyz.svc` is variable. For example a in a second case the string value would be

```
https://<host_name>/path/object.svc/path1/path2|https://<host_name>/path/abcd.svc/path3/path4.
```

I would like to have a generic Regex pattern that I can use so that I want to skip the `object.svc` and only select `xyz.svc`, `abcd.svc` etc. Basically a regex where I want to find all `.svc` where it is NOT `object.svc`.

Anyone has any suggestions as to how this can be done ?

Comment: What language are you in? Available RegEx patterns vary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using Javascript you could use **look behind** `(?<!object)` with something like: `\w+(?<!object)\.svc`

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/rT9yE4/1)

If still would want to match words that contains object like 'sobject' for example you could add the **`\b`** to the look behind expression like: `\w+(?<!\bobject)\.svc` and this will force a match of only the word `object.svc`

Please note that **`\w`** will match [a-zA-Z0-9_] if only excluding numbers or excluding the `_` is necessary you may need to change the \w with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

As correctly highlighted and commented by **@AlanMoore:**

A lookahead will work just as well: `\b(?!object\.svc\b)\w+\.svc\b`. But, as you said, we can't know if `\w+` is correct, which means `\b` might not be right either. It might be best to use the surrounding slashes to anchor the match, and a capturing group to retrieve it: `/((?!object\.svc/)[^/]+\.svc)/`

Comment: A lookahead will work just as well: `\b(?!object\.svc\b)\w+\.svc\b`.  But, as you said, we can't know if `\w+` is correct, which means `\b` might not be right either.  It might be best to use the surrounding slashes to anchor the match, and a capturing group to retrieve it: `/((?!object\.svc/)[^/]+\.svc)/`